# Why is Entity framework loading data from the db when I set a property?

Tags: entity-framework-4, poco

I have two tables (there are more in the database but only two are involved here).
Account and AccountStatus, an account can have an AccountStatus (active,inactive etc).

I create a new Account and set a couple of properties but when I reach this code:
1. var status = db.AccountStatuses.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == (long)AccountStatusEnum.Active);
2. account.AccountStatus = status;
3. db.Accounts.AddObject(account);
The first line executes fine, but when I reach the second line it takes a REALLY long time, and when I step in to the code it seems that every single account is loaded from the database.

I don't see why it should even want to load all the accounts?
We use Entity Framework 4 and Poco and we have lazy loading enabled.

Any suggestions?
Cheers
/Jimmy

Comment: Can you show whole code of account creation?

Comment: The account creation isn't that spectacular ;)
These are the lines just before the code posted above.
var account = new Account();
account.SourceSystemClientID = "";
account.AccountNumber = "...";
account.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
account.LastModifiedBy = "Customer";
account.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful which constructs you use to fetch data, as some will pull in the whole set and filter afterword.  (aside: the long time delay may be the database being created and seeded, if there isn't one already, it will occur the first time you touch it, likely with a query of some sort.  Also remember that when you retrieve a whole dataset, you may in actuality only have what amounts to a compiled query that won't be evaluated until you interact with it).

Try this form instead and see if you have the same issue:

```
var status = db.AccountStatuses.Where(s => s.ID == (long)AccountStatusEnum.Active);
```

Comment: A good way to prevent getting surprised by these types of issues (more data being loaded than you expected) is to disable lazy loading - then only things you *explicitly* load will get loaded.

Comment: But isn't it strange that it loads (what I think is all the accounts, I haven't infact verifed that it's ALL the accounts) just because I set the AccountStatus Property?

Comment: I ended up disabeling Lazyloading on the context where I did the update by specifying db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;